Error connecting to DB2 using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries
Trying to connect to DB2 using the Nuget pkg IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries 7.1.0 by Cristopher Gunn. The program throws an exception "The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Trace' threw an exception"
The code is simply - Using conn As New iDB2Connection()
This is after moving to a new server from AS400.  Any ideas?  I can connect using Dbeaver and IBM iSeries
Was running this on my server so i didn't see the inner exception. The inner exception was Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions,.... So I added that and the next run gave the exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.AccessControl,.... so added that and the next run gave {"Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.EventWaitHandle..ctor(Boolean, System.Threading.EventResetMode, System.String, Boolean ByRef, System.Security.AccessControl.EventWaitHandleSecurity)'."}
Do I need to target .net framework?  I am targeting 8.0.

Why would you use a nuget package from some 3rd party that hasn't been updated since 2015 instead of the IBM provided drivers available as part of IBM ACS

Looks like an active nuget pkg that is being used. I'll try IBM ACS again.

You mean the stuff from 2005?  I just go in circles.
